# In Nodejs, how to start several processes and wait for their completion?

Tags: node.js, typescript, spawn

In Node.js, using TypeScript, I want to start several processes, using the function `spawn`, and then I want to wait for the completion of all of them before executing another command.

Answer (score 0):

1. Wrap the call to `spawn` in a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) calling the `resolve` function from the [close event](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#event-close).
2. Put all the promises generated that way in an array and pass it to [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)
3. [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) that promise returned by Promise.all.